# How to handle returned data as undefined that needs to be added to a useQuery hook in apollo and reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

I have the following code but it renders the cookieData undefined on the first render and query, so the query doesn't get the cookie and it fails authetication. Any way to make the query wait for the call to the cookie api to come back before running.

```
const { data: cookieData, error: cookieError } = useSWR(
    "/api/cookie",
    fetcher
  );

  console.log(cookieData);


  var test = `Bearer ${cookieData}`;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FORMS, {
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: test,
      },
    },
  });
```

UPDATE: I ended up using lazy query for the above, but I will try skip as well, but I have been trying to implement skip on this mutation now and it says the id is undefined, it consoles on the page but is undfined first a few times.

```
const addFormClicked = async (data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    const res = await createForm({
      variables: {
        name: data.name,
        user: user.id,
      },
      skip: !user.id,
    });
    console.log(res);
    Router.push(`/formBuild/${res.data.createForm._id}`);
  };
```

Here's the whole code for context

```
import { useMutation, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { FORMS } from "../components/Layout";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useState } from "react";

const ADD_FORM = gql`
  mutation AddForm($name: String!, $id: ID!) {
    createForm(data: { name: $name, user: { connect: $id } }) {
      name
      _id
    }
  }
`;

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

export default function AddForm() {
  const { data: user } = useSWR("/api/user"); // add

  const { data: cookieData, error: cookieError } = useSWR(
    "/api/cookie",
    fetcher
  );

  var test = `Bearer ${cookieData}`;

  const Router = useRouter();

  const [
    createForm,
    {
      data: createFormData,
      error: createFormError,
      loading: createFormLoading,
    },
  ] = useMutation(ADD_FORM, {
    refetchQueries: [{ query: FORMS }],
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: test,
      },
    },
  });

  const addFormClicked = async (data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    const res = await createForm({
      variables: {
        name: data.name,
        user: user.id,
      },
      skip: !user.id,
    });
    console.log(res);
    Router.push(`/formBuild/${res.data.createForm._id}`);
  };

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm();

  if (createFormLoading) return <p>Loading</p>;
  if (createFormError) return <p>Error: {createFormError.message}</p>;

  //console.log(createFormData);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addFormClicked)}>
        <h1>Form Name</h1>
        <input type="text" name="name" ref={register()} />
        <button type="submit">Add Form</button>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

UPDATE: The user needed to be id, seen below

```
 const addFormClicked = async (data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    const res = await createForm({
      variables: {
        name: data.name,
        id: user.id, //NOT user:user.id BUT id:user.id
      },
      skip: !user.id,
    });
    console.log(res);
    Router.push(`/formBuild/${res.data.createForm._id}`);
  };
```

Comment: ... `skip` option

Comment: ok so I pass skip true, how do I then rerun when the cookieData is back

Comment: .... ... why true?

Comment: @AndersKitson You only want to skip the query if `cookieData` is `undefined` - `skip: !cookieData`.

Comment: so I changed the question a bit, I solved the first one with lazyquery, but I will try skip as well, but could you help me understand why the skip is not working for user.id, user.id consoles, but it has some undefineds the first few times

Comment: I don't work with next but ... you're doing something wrong ... it's a mess ... mixing contexts, authed routes ... why you're artificially "flattening" this? you probably need a `<FormPage/>` (with route/auth querying) rendering a layout (and 'external loading') and `<Form/>` component with user passed as a prop doing ONLY FORM ACTIONS (own 'loading' while querying/processing mutation) ... but ... why not to use auth user data (cookie/token middleware) implicitly in resolver?

Comment: hmm I don't know what you mean by artificially flattening this. There is a lot to unpack here. Why not use cookie token middleware in resolver? what does that mean?

Comment: and it's more of an apollo issue I am having over next

Comment: fixed it, needed id key not user, Thanks for the help, and I am open to any criticism. Cheers

Comment: **S**ingle responsiblitity ... make form component reusable, renderable in other contexts/pages/structures (like that, not this use case, but this pattern), should not depend on user/route/etc ... components are a cheap abstraction in react ... `createForm` should be a mutation for authed users, that way you should have in context arg current user data (recognized in middleware), use it instead of passing user as arg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user` variable will be `undefined` while the query is in a `loading` state. Same with `cookieData`. There's no `skip` option available in [`useMutation`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usemutation) since it does not automatically execute the mutation when the component renders.

A simple solution would be to render the form if only if `user` and `cookieData` exist. This way, you can know for sure the user id and token will be available when the form gets submitted.

```js
// Add `userError` to use in combination with `user` to check if the query is loading
const { data: user, error: userError } = useSWR('/api/user', userFetcher)

const [
  createForm,
  { data: createFormData, error: createFormError, loading: createFormLoading },
] = useMutation(ADD_FORM, {
  refetchQueries: [{ query: FORMS }],
})

const addFormClicked = async (data) => {
  const res = await createForm({
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${cookieData}`,
      },
    },
    variables: {
      name: data.name,
      user: user.id,
    },
  })
  Router.push(`/formBuild/${res.data.createForm._id}`)
}

if (userError || cookieError) {
  return <div>Something went wrong</div>
}

if (!user || !cookieData) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

// Render form
```